# Error while writing to file

Tags: java

> ```
> package test_package2;
>
> import java.io.*;
>
> public class File_Directory_Operations {
>
>     public void FileOperation() {
>         try {
>             byte[] bWtite = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
>             OutputStream objOS = new FileOutputStream("F:/Shiju/Test Programmes/Eclipse/testjava.txt");
>           for (int iCount = 0; iCount < bWtite.length; iCount++) {
>                 objOS.write(bWtite[iCount]);
>             }
>             objOS.close();
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>               System.out.println(e.toString());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I am new to Java.I am able to create the file and write into it, but instead of the expected byte array I am getting series of characters inside the file. Why am I not able to print the array?

Comment: Please, paste again your code in a readable format.

Comment: because you are casting it to char?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a byte array, convert `char[]` to `byte[]` then use `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to read the byte Array.

```
        InputStream objIS = new FileInputStream("F:/Shiju/Test Programmes/Eclipse/testjava.txt");

        int iSize = objIS.available();
        byte[] bytesToBeRed = new byte[ iSize ];
        objIS.read( bytesToBeRed  );
        objIS.close();
```